# how modify path in asp-action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a form in C# ASP, and two buttons submit with different path.

```
<form asp-action="">

<button type="submit" data-action="Liquidation" class="btn-method-switchable">
<button type="submit" data-action="Return" class="btn-method-switchable">
```

I try to modify the path with Jquery like that :

```
$('.btn-method-switchable').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
let value = $(this).data('action')
$('form').attr('asp-action', value);
$('form').submit();
})
```

I enter in my Controller but not on the method Liquidation or Return.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asp-action` attribute is only used before rendering. When the page is rendered it's converted to a standard HTML form `action` attribute.

Also note that on the client side its value is converted from the reference to the action name to a relative URL to the route. More detail on that in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-form-tag-helper).

Therefore to correct your code you need to set the `action` attribute and also amend `data-action` on the `button` elements to be the full route. This can be done using the `Url.Action()` helper. The code would look something like this:

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit" data-action="@Url.Action("Liquidation")" class="btn-method-switchable">Foo</button>
  <button type="submit" data-action="@Url.Action("Return")" class="btn-method-switchable">Bar</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('.btn-method-switchable').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let value = $(this).data('action')
  $('form').attr('action', value).submit();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, finally I used the C# attribute "formaction" because with the jquery I do not understand why, I enter well in the good controller but that put me on a method that I do not call.